# How to rewrite the following code using a for loop in Verilog?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, system-verilog, rtl

Is it possible to write the following code using a `for` loop in Verilog?

```
i = 0: sum[0] <= data[0];
i = 1: sum[1] <= data[0] + data[1];
i = 2: sum[2] <= data[0] + data[1] + data[2];
i = 3: sum[3] <= data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3];
.
.
i = 7: sum[7] <= data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3] + data[4] + data[5] + data[6] + data[7];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of `for` loops and a `function`:

```
logic [3:0] sum [8];
logic [7:0] data;

function logic [3:0] sum_data (int n);
    sum_data = data[0];
    for (int j=1; j<=n; j++) begin
        sum_data += data[j];
    end
endfunction

// ...

for (int i=0; i<8; i++) begin
    sum[i] <= sum_data(i);
end
```

Functions are synthesizable.